# How to output command specific output in commanderjs?

Tags: javascript, command-line, node-commander

I am building a simple command line app in node using commander js. The problem is, when I run a particular command, it outputs the result of an other command as well.

I've tried multiple things but nothing seems to be working out. 
I have two crawler objects as below in crawler.js file

```
var f = new Crawler({ 
//code here
}); 

var c = new Crawler({ 
//code here
});

c.queue("http://www.someurl.com")
f.queue("http://www.someurl.com")
module.exports = {
  c,
  f
};
```

My index.js file looks like this

```
const x =() => {
crawler.c;
}
const y =() => {
crawler.f
}
program
.command("x")
.action(()=>{
    x();
});

program
    .command("y")
    .action(()=>{
        y();
    });
```

Whenever I call the command x, it fires y as well and vice versa. 
I need to show command specific outputs. Please help.

Comment: It would be helpful to include working code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the code in x and y intended to do? It appears to just reference the exported objects from crawler, bot not perform any actions.